# Лиса Патрикеевна

Tags: фольклор

Лиса Патрикеевна — персонаж русских сказок. Но интересно, почему ей дали именно такое "отчество"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Отчество - от литовского князя Патрикея, известного своей хитростью и пронырливостью*
(Вики)